# Why i'm getting error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is the code i'm using:

```
<?php 
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)"; //valid image extensions 
$files = array(); 
$curimage=0; 
if($handle = opendir($"http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files")) { 
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){ 
        if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image 
            //Output it as a JavaScript array element 
            $files[] = $file; 
            $curimage++; 
        } 
    } 
    closedir($handle); 
} 
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
      <title>change picture</title>

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    #Timer_Countdown{
    background:black;
    color:yellow;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
}
  </style>

      <script type = "text/javascript">

          function displayNextImage() {
              x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

          function displayPreviousImage() {
              x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
              document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
          }

var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
//var images = [];
var x = -1; 
var swap_hours = 0;
var swap_minutes = 0;
var swap_seconds = 5;

var down_counter_hours;
var down_counter_minutes;
var down_counter_seconds;

function initTimer() {

    down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
    down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
    down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
    counter = setInterval(switcher, 1000);
}

function restartCounter() {
        down_counter_hours = swap_hours;
        down_counter_minutes = swap_minutes;
        down_counter_seconds = swap_seconds;
}

function switcher() {
    down_counter_seconds--;
    if (down_counter_hours <= 0 && down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_seconds <= 0) {
        swapColor();
        restartCounter();
    }
    if (down_counter_seconds <= 0 && down_counter_minutes > 0) {
        down_counter_seconds = 60;
        down_counter_minutes--;
    }
    if (down_counter_minutes <= 0 && down_counter_hours > 0) {
        down_counter_minutes = 60;
        down_counter_hours--;
    }

    document.getElementById("Timer_Countdown").innerText =        down_counter_hours+":"+down_counter_minutes+":"+down_counter_seconds;
}

function swapColor() {
    displayNextImage();
}

      </script>
      <div id="div_hours" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_minutes" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_seconds" class="div_box"></div>
      <div id="div_switcher" class="div_box"></div>
   </head>

   <body onload = "initTimer()">
       <div id="Timer_Countdown">&nbsp;</div>
       <img id="img" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/radar000005.Gif">
       <button onclick="displayPreviousImage(); restartCounter()">Previous</button>
       <button onclick="displayNextImage(); restartCounter()">Next</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

The error is on the line:

```
var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;
```

If i change this line to this line:

```
var images = [];
```

Then the code is working fine but without using the php files variable.
Something is wrong with the line: `var images = <?=json_encode($files)?>;`

I tried to change this line to: `echo json_encode($images);` or to `var images = echo json_encode($files);` but same error.

I'm using weebly to build my site and my site server is on ipage.com

How can i fix the error ?

Comment: `<?=json_encode($files)?>` isn't a valid javascript expression.

Comment: Is all of your code in a PHP file?

Comment: Hit *"View page source"* in your browser. The problem should be apparent then

Comment: showdev no the php code is only what i show in my question it's above the html code. I don't have any php file on my server(filemanager of my site).

Comment: Without some [server-side configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574306/executing-php-code-inside-a-js-file#answer-23574475), you won't be able to execute PHP code from a file that is not `.php`.

Comment: I saw this now in weebly.com site: Can I use PHP, MySQL and Other Server-Side Languages?
" You can edit your site with HTML, CSS and Javascript (client-side languages); however, Weebly does not support building your site with server-side languages, such as PHP or ASP. We also do not currently offer database access." is that mean i can't use php at all ?

Comment: Phil's view page source would clearly clarify that - if all of your php code is present in the page output, then there's no php interpreter to work on it.

Comment: Sacho i did view source and the php code is there marked in green but the code is there.

Comment: It shouldn't be. As mentioned by Sacho, PHP code is intended to be executed on the server,  generating HTML code for the browser. You should never see PHP code in your page source. This indicates that your PHP code is not being executed.

Comment: This is bad i'm paying weebly and they are not supporting php. I should have check it before signing with them.

Comment: Is there any other sites like weebly.com but that support php ? Maybe free or not free but something good that support also php.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have short tags enabled(and are using a pre 5.4 php version), thus the line `<?=json_encode($files)?>` is not parsed by php and is just send straight through. var images = <... is not a valid javascript expression. Here's some information about php's short_open_tag parameter: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

Comment: `<?=` isn't part of short-open-tags anymore. OP also tried `<?php echo`

Comment: No, he did not. He also didn't list his php version.

Comment: Well, he kind of did but it's not entirely clear so I'll give you the benefit of the doubt

Comment: How did he "kind of"? It doesn't mention doing so anywhere.

Comment: From the OP ~ *"I tried to change this line to: echo json_encode($images); or to var images = echo json_encode($files); but same error."* I agree, it's hard to tell *exactly* what OP has tried though. Edit: seems OP isn't using PHP on the server at all

Comment: This is generally why I avoid posting answers before clarifying with the OP, but occam's razor suggested that as long as he was right about the line of the error, that this would be the problem. In hindsight, the possibility of there being *no php support at all* would produce the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of changes. Change

```
$pattern ="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$) |(\.Gif$)";
```

to

```
$pattern = '/\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i';
```

and

```
eregi($pattern, $file)
```

to

```
preg_match($pattern, $file)
```

and see what happens. `eregi` deprecated as PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score -2):

You are using '=' inside the PHP tags. Try this:

```
var images = <?json_encode($files)?>;
```

Comment: `<?=` is short for `<?php echo`.