# PHP if else condition inside JS file Wordpress theme customizer condition

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

```
$('.class1').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class1.load-more');
```

the above is a code from the `.js` file of WP infinite scroll Wordpress plugin.

Can we somehow put a PHP condition inside a js file:

```
If( logical condition 1 )  {
    $('.class1').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class1.load-more');
} elseif( logical condition 2 )  {
    $('.class2').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class2 .load-more');
}
```

P.S.: PHP logic should go inside a `js` file not `script<></script>` tags.

Comment: [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: I think it's not duplicate here she is not dealing with code written in HTML file in `<script><./script>` please under her question correctly instead of labeling it as a duplicate. Her code is in `.js`  file where she wants a PHP logic based some JS lines.

Comment: @somethingnow the problem is still the same. PHP is server side code. PHP can be used to compose any kind of file (html, css, js)  server side, and then send it to the client. But it is a server side php file that holds the php condition and then builds a JS file out of it.

Comment: @t.niese suggest a solution to her.

Comment: [Executing PHP code inside a .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574306)

Comment: This entirely depends on what condition you want to check and whether that's even possible given the [difference between server and client side programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming). At least you're probably approaching the problem the wrong way. It's hard to suggest the *right* way without more details.

Comment: It is based on what we have seklected in theme customizer. Condition will be like this ☻6 http://aristath.github.io/kirki/docs/controls/select.html. Class will change based on the condition selcted in theme customizer of WP.

Answer (score 0):

define a other js file example condition.js

----- condition.js

```
<?php 
echo 'condition ..... ;
?>
```

---- condition.js

```
// condution.js output 
var lc = [ function(){return false;} , function(){ return x *y; }  ];
```

.

```
if( lc[0]() )  {
    $('.class1').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class1.load-more');
} elseif( lc[1]() )  {
    $('.class2').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class2 .load-more');
}
```

---- OR -----

```
// condution.js output
var lc = [ true , 0 ];
```

After

```
if( lc[0] )  {
    $('.class1').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class1.load-more');
} elseif( lc[1] )  {
    $('.class2').append( '<span class="load-more"></span>' );
    var button = $('.class2 .load-more');
}
```

Comment: Plese do not write solution in `script<></script>` tags.

Comment: examined again.

Comment: I need to take some time to implement this then I will write back to you.

Comment: theme customzier select logic will work like this : `<?php if ( grid == get_theme_mod( 'show_authorbox_1' ) ) : ?>` @Hasan you now knwo aht logic is there for PHP. (I gave an example)

Comment: You must tell condition to javascript.
JavaScript run only **<script>** tags and *<script src=... > ** tags.
You can create a .js file and include <script src=newfile.js>  or you can use <?php echo <script> .... ?> ... other side javascript can not run condition or any data.