# not able to get the php variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my php script I have variable like below.

`$duration = 60;`

Now I'm accessing the above PHP variable in javascirpt.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var phpVar = '<?php echo $duration; ?>';
    console.log(phpVar );
 </script>
```

But in the console I'm getting the whole data instead of 60. That is, output is

```
 '<?php echo $duration; ?>'
```

Please help me how to access the php variable properly.

Thanks.

Comment: Whatever file you put this in, did not get parsed as PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574306/executing-php-code-inside-a-js-file

Comment: It's working with single quotes, double quotes and without quotes, there is no issue with the code, make sure you file as .php

Comment: you shouldn't mix PHP + JS like this - they get executed differently. Much better to use AJAX and get the value from a script, assign it to a var that way.

Comment: You're setting `$duration` but echoing `$simple`. However the PHP output suggests you've saved the file as `*.html` instead of `*.php`

Comment: `$duration` or `$simple`?

Comment: `$duration` IS NOT `$simple` ??

Comment: edited the question with $duration

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var phpVar = <?php echo $duration; ?>;
  console.log(phpVar);
});
```

Put $duration instead if $simple.

Comment: eidited the question with $duration. But it is not evaluating the php statement. It is considering as normal string.

Comment: I tried this same code. it's running perfect