# php variable display in js

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

I have been trying to show php variables in javascript like this:

```
<body>
<?php
$v = "random";
echo "<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('<?php echo($v); ?>');
</script>"
?>
</body>
```

But this does not show any output in the browser. Why is that?

Comment: you are echoing inside an echo statement

Comment: ^ And using an open tag.

Comment: all the below examples are printing script tag using echo, instead you should use echo only to print the variable value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use PHP's string concatenation to do this:

```
<body>
<?php
$v = "random";
echo "<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('" . $v . "');
</script>"
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some misplaced tags. Try with this code:

```
<body>
<?php
$v = "random";
echo "<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('$v')";
?>
</script>
</body>
```

HTML Output:

```
<body>
<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('random')</script>
</body>
```

Comment: that is wrong as well, stray single quote

Comment: I edit but the code works in my browser

Comment: you just copied! also php has nothing to do with browsers

Comment: this code and the previous works and make as output *random* in the browser

Comment: nope it won't, if it was working then revert your edit and keep the old code in your answer

Comment: @Mr.Alien I edit again and it works again

Comment: that is not the code which you had written when i had commented

Answer (score 0):

instead

```
document.write('<?php echo($v); ?>');
```

try

```
document.write('$v');
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already opened php with `<?php` and already invoked the `echo` call.

It is best to concatenate the variable by closing the quotes and using a period:

```
echo "<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('". $v ."');
</script>";
```

Like Mr.Alien said in the comments, it doesn't appear you need to echo the Javascript.  You can just invoke PHP where you need to echo the variable.  If your install supports short tags, you can do this:

```
<body>
<script language='javascript'> 
document.write('<?= $v ?>');
</script>
</body>
```

`<?= $v ?>` is a short tag for `<?php echo $v; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

for a good practice of programming

and  for easy mainting the code between javascript and php

store the php value to a variable and use it in javascript

```
<?php
    $v = 'random';
?>

<script>
    // store the php variable into a javascript variable
    // for this instance you can use the javascript variable v
    // in any script file if you define the variable v to be global
    var v = '<?php echo $v; ?>';
    // print it out

    // it is more readable for other user reading it
    document.write(v);
</script>
```

a good link also

**[How to embed php in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript)**

Comment: An explanation of how this works or what you've fixed would boost the answer's useful tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="hidden" id="msg" value="<?php echo $v;?>">
```

and then call it from JS

```
var msg = document.getElementById('msg').value;
document.write(msg);
```

should work

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to see the value of the PHP variable on the web page, you could use this:

```
<body>
<?php $v = "random"; ?>
<p>This is the PHP variable <?php echo $v ?></p>
</body>
```