# My php is not interpreted in my Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I create my HTML this way

```
 $('<form>')
     .attr('method',"POST")
     .attr('action',"postMetier.php?metier="+"<?php echo $GET['metier'] ?>")
```

How can I make the echo work ?

Comment: And this is probably in a .js file that isn't parsed by PHP?

Comment: It won't parse unless your file extension is .php or .phtml.

Comment: `.attr('action',"postMetier.php?" + location.search)`

Comment: You are right Adeneo, I have a php extension :)

Comment: http://imgur.com/28DnHi1

Comment: What i'm trying to do is this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript but none of the methods that I found work for me .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript
Solved using the first anwser

Answer (score 1):

`$GET` variable doesn't exists, correct name is `$_GET`.

```
.attr('action',"postMetier.php?metier="+"<?php echo $_GET['metier'] ?>")
                                                     ^
```

Of course, you JS code has to be in PHP file (or other which is parsed by server).

Answer (score 1):

it is not `$GET['metier']` but `$_GET['metier']`, if there is value recieved on your page by get method then `echo $GET['metier']` will give you some value.

**Note:** if `$GET['metier']` is your defined variable, then it should have some value in it so that it can be echoed.