# How to use <select> tag id in javascript. When id is PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have HTML `<select>` tag ID. I need to track with javascript, which option is selected

My html `<select>` id:

```
<select id="<?php echo $userArray[$key]["userID"]?>">
```

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#selectionButton').click(function(){
            var selectedValue = $("#<?php echo json_encode($userArray[$key]['userID']);?>").val();
            window.alert(selectedValue);
        });
    });
```

How to use PHP array as HTML id in javascript?

Comment: I've read that people are using  json_encode wenn putting php in javascript.Am not right?

Comment: How to embed php in js: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript

Comment: Also, make sure the ID doesn't include any spaces and make sure to escape special characters, or the jQuery selector won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The point here is not about using particularly only PHP `array` values as your potential event target identifier, it's generally about using dynamicly generated data as part of elements' `id` attributes. Here you would better target `class` instead of `id` in your JS. So, when the event fires you check target's `id` value.

```
$(document).on('click', '.i-am-target-class', function () {
    var targetId = $(this).attr('id');
    // do your stuff knowing id
});
```

And what you are trying to do passing PHP code as your event target in your JS is far far not the best solution on the market

**UPD:**

```
PHP:
<select id="<?php echo $userArray[$key]['userID']; ?>" class="value-to-save"></select>

JS:
var results = {};

$('#save-button').click(function () {
    $('.value-to-save').each(function () {
        var userId = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
        results[userId] = value;
    });
});
```

So in the end you will get `results` object with all your data

Comment: ok, what is the better way to pass it.If i have for example 100 rows from database, and i need 100 dropdownlists?

Comment: it doesn't matter how many rows do you have, give them all unique dynamic id and common class and bind your event to this class, then when event is fired on one of the elements you just check the id of the particular event target

Comment: Could you give me a simple  example?It would be very usefull for me.Thanks

Comment: how many unique <select> elements with dynamicly generated id attribute you are expecting in your document?

Comment: From 10 to 30 maybe.I have users information from database, and i need dropdownlist for every user in row isAdmin.

Comment: and will you have selectionButton for each of them?

Comment: Am planning to make one "save information" button for all changed user data

Comment: Thanks.It will be very helpfull for me