# How To? PHP echo data from within <script>

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, schema

I'm at best a VERY novice programmer (hobbiest at best), i'm stuck on a piece of code i'm working on to implement Schema markup in to my Wordpress site.

Here's what i'm trying to solve.

```html
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "Festival",
  "name": "<?php the_title(); ?>",
  "url": "http://www.trancemusicevents.com/fbevent/solarstone-presents-pure-trance-helsinki-2017/",
  "description": " <?php the_excerpt(); ?>",
  "location": {
    "@type": "Place",
    "name": "The Circus Salomonkatu 13 Helsinki",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "<?php fbe_event_address(); ?>",
      "addressLocality": "Helsinki",
      "addressCountry": "Finland"
    }
  }
}
 </script>
```

So where i have  ,   and  i'm trying to call custom post meta from Wordpress.

I've tried searching how to use php within the  tags but found no joy. I basically just want to echo the meta data from the relevant Wordpress meta fields.

Any help is welcome, please excuse my novice approach to coding!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript should help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the output of the_title for JOSN:

```
"name": "<?php echo esc_js(get_the_title()); ?>",
```

You can echo other custom fields the same way:

```
"field": "<?php echo esc_js(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_field_id', true)); ?>",
```