# How to put PHP code into JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to define a value by `PHP echo` with data received from MySQL.

How to put `PHP echo` code into JavaScript?

Example:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var gg1 = new JustGage({
        id: "gg1",
        value: <?php echo 'Hello World!' ?>
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: "Target",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed php in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript)

Comment: it would work! youre just missing a **,** behind your value data...

Comment: Try this,
            value: '<?php echo 'Hello World!' ?>',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed the quotation around the `<?php` & semi-colon before `?>`,

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var gg1 = new JustGage({
        id: "gg1",
        value: "<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>", // This line is edited
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        title: "Target",
```

Comment: Also missed basic syntax like the  semi-colon to end your echo string, 
`'Hello World!'` should be `'Hello World!';`

If you have it turned on in your php.ini file, you can also use ' <?=$variable?> '.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Php varibale inside Javascript or JQuery call them like this..

```
var example ="<?php echo date();?>";
```