# Embed PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to embed `PHP` into `Javascript` so that when the user selects `Countries` it would display the result from the query alphabatically and if he selects `Numbers` then list based on numbers in descending.

Having researched, I have applied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript) (`echo` concept into my code) but doesn't seem to work.

I have the following query written in PHP that output staffs' country of birth( no of staff born in number of countries) in ascending order:

```
$querytest = "select x , COUNT( * )  from( select `staffbirthplace` as x from staffbirthdetails where staffemailid IN(SELECT staffemailid FROM staff where orgid='" . $orgId . "'  AND deptname='" . $deptName . "' AND teamname='" . $teamName . "') ) as temptable group by x order by count(*) ASC ";
```

Then, I have a dropdown in `HTML`:

```
<form>
    <label for="sortorder">Sort by:</label>
    <select id="sortByDropdown" onchange="sortBy(this);">
      <option value="alphabatically">Countries</option>
      <option value="numbers">Number</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Furthermore, I have a `Javascript` function `sortBy()`

```
function sortBy(){
    var sortByDrpdownDiv =  document.getElementById('sortByDropdown');

if (sortByDrpdownDiv[sortByDrpdownDiv.selectedIndex].value == 'numbers'){
    alert("yo in if statement");
    <?php $querytest = "select x , COUNT( * ) from( select `staffbirthplace` as x from staffbirthdetails where staffemailid IN(SELECT staffemailid FROM staff where orgid='" . $orgId . "'  AND deptname='" . $deptName . "' AND teamname='" . $teamName . "') ) as temptable group by x order by count(*) DESC ";
    $result = mysql_query($querytest);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "<b>";
            echo $row['x'];
            echo ": </b>&nbsp;";
            echo $row['COUNT( * )'];
            echo "<br/>";
        }?>
    document.getElementById('staffbirthplaces').innerHTML = <?php echo $row?>;
    }
}
```

First I am going only for `Numbers`because the same logic will apply to the `Countries`. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: PHP is server side scripts. JavaScript is client side scripts. You can't embed PHP into JavaScript. Are you trying to use PHP to print some JavaScript code?

Comment: You must use ajax

Comment: I gathered that from the linked answer in my question. No, I am trying to display the query's(written in PHP) result in my Javascript function somehow

Comment: This is not possible. Client asks for the page; then server executes the PHP and outputs the response; then client draws the HTML/CSS and executes the JavaScript. You can't "climb back in time" to execute PHP again once your web page is on the client. You must use another request, tell the server to send some more data your way, then render it.

Comment: So, use Ajax or connect to the database over again (which can be a nifty process from performance perspective) and was avoiding that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed php in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-to-embed-php-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

So, i finally did it! Used `switch` instead of `IF statement`. Below is the code:

```
   function sortByAlphabetsOrNumbers(obj){

    var selectedValue = obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].value
switch(selectedValue)
{
    case "numberOfStaff":
        document.getElementById('sortBy').innerHTML = 
        "<?php
            include 'connection.php';

            $staffNumbersDesc = "select x , COUNT( * )  from( select `staffbirthplace` as x from staffbirthdetails where staffemailid IN(SELECT staffemailid FROM staff where orgid='" . $orgId . "'  AND deptname='" . $deptName . "' AND teamname='" . $teamName . "') ) as temptable group by x order by count(*) DESC";
            $result = mysql_query($staffNumbersDesc);               
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                echo "<b>";
                echo $row['x'];
                echo ": </b>&nbsp;";
                echo $row['COUNT( * )'];
                echo "<br/>";
                } 
        ?>";
        document.getElementById('birthCountriesAlphabaticalOrder').style.display = "none";
        break;

    case "countries":
        document.getElementById('sortBy').innerHTML = 
        "<?php
            include 'connection.php';

            $alphabaticalOrder = "select x , COUNT( * )  from( select `staffbirthplace` as x from staffbirthdetails where staffemailid IN(SELECT staffemailid FROM staff where orgid='" . $orgId . "'  AND deptname='" . $deptName . "' AND teamname='" . $teamName . "') ) as temptable group by x";
            $result = mysql_query($alphabaticalOrder);              
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            {
                echo "<b>";
                echo $row['x'];
                echo ": </b>&nbsp;";
                echo $row['COUNT( * )'];
                echo "<br/>";
                } 
        ?>";
        document.getElementById('birthCountriesAlphabaticalOrder').style.display = "none";
        break;
}
};
```

Hope it helps someone