# Return a specific record from mysql database and display it to TinyMCE text area editor so the user can edit the note

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I need to retrieve a record from mysql database and set it into a TinyMCE text editor area.

I created this template so it can act as my guide:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tnstudentregistrationdb");

$selectNote = "SELECT notes FROM studentNotes WHERE noteid = 61";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $selectNote);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--JQuery-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
        <title>TinyMCE - Set Data</title>
        
        <script src="./TinyMCE/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

            <textarea class="tinymce" id="texteditor"></textarea>
            <textarea class="tinymce2" id="texteditor2"></textarea>
            <button class="set-data-btn-class" id="set-data-btn-id" >Set Data</button>
            
            <button class="update-data-btn-class" id="update-data-btn-id" >Update Data</button>
        <!-- javascript -->
        <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#set-data-btn-id").on("click", function(e) {
        
        var content = `<?php echo $content = $row["notes"]; ?>`;                 //remember to only use single quote marks around <?php ?> tag
        console.log(content);
        tinymce.get("texteditor").setContent(content);

    });
        
        
        $("#update-data-btn-id").on("click", function(e) {
            
            
        });
        
        });
        
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#texteditor, #texteditor2',
            width: '100%', 
  
        });
        
        
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

It does the desired functionality. $selectNote is the php mysql query to select a specific note, $result uses mysqli_query() to execute the sql query, and $row fetches the first row of results from the query.

```
$("#set-data-btn-id").on("click", function(e) {
        
        var content = `<?php echo $content = $row["notes"]; ?>`; //remember to only use single quote marks around <?php ?> tag
        console.log(content);
        tinymce.get("texteditor").setContent(content);

    });
```

This sets the content of #texteditor TinyMCE based on JS my JS content variable's value which is the first results of my PHP $row variable.

I tried to mimic this implementation to my main system:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tnstudentregistrationdb");

if (isset($_POST["note_id"])) {
    $output = '';

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tnstudentregistrationdb");  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM studentNotes WHERE noteid = '".$_POST["note_id"]."'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  

    $querySpecific = "SELECT notes FROM studentNotes WHERE noteid = 61";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $querySpecific);
    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

    $output .= '  
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="selectNoteStyle.css"/>-->
    <!--There seems to be a problem with my external CSS, for now we will just use inline CSS-->

    <style>
    #deleteAndEditContainerID{
      text-align: left;
      
    }
  
  
  #noteTitleSelected {
      text-align: center;
      
  }
  
  #accessibilityOptionsID {
      float: right;
      
  }
  
  #noteContentID {
      width: 90%; 
      display: inline-block;
  }

  table, th, td, tr {
    /*We can also use ID and class to better specify which element to style, but since we only have one table
    in this component, we can also just call the entire table*/

    border: none;
  }
    </style>

    <script>
      
$(document).ready(
  function mode(){
  $("#darkMode").click(function(){
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.backgroundColor = "#ffcc66";
       document.getElementById("noteContentRow").style.backgroundColor = "#ffcc66";
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.color = "white";
      });
  
      $("#lightMode").click(function(){
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.backgroundColor = "white";
       document.getElementById("noteContentRow").style.backgroundColor = "white";
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.color = "black";
      });


      $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
       //Basically, .attr() gets the attribute value from $(this).attr("id"). so this could be $(".className").attr("id"), the id of the .className is selected.
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
       
       var title_note = $("#noteTitleSelected").text();
       var title_id_note = $("#noteIDSelected").text();

       $("#titleDeletingNoteID").text(title_note);
       $("#titleID").text(title_id_note);

       $("#myModal").modal("hide");
 
       
     }); //End of line for $(".deleteButton").click(function()){};

     
     $(".editButton").click(function(){
       //Basically, .attr() gets the attribute value from $(this).attr("id"). so this could be $(".className").attr("id"), the id of the .className is selected.
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
       
       $("#myModal").modal("hide");

       var content = "<?php echo $content = $row1["notes"]";
       //Try to use an external JavaScript file, using quotes in this js code is causing problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-do-i-embed-php-code-in-javascript
       console.log(content);
       tinymce.get("editNoteArea").setContent(content);
       
     }); //End of line for $(".editButton").click(function()){};
   
    
 });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>  
         <table >';  
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
         $output .= '  
              
                 <h2 id="noteTitleSelected">'.$row["noteTitle"].'</h2>
                 <h4 id="noteIDSelected">'.$row["noteid"].'</h4> <!--Make Delete and Edit functional-->
                 <div id="menuAbove">
                 <label><i>Timestamp: '.$row["note_timestamp"].'</i></label>
                 
                 <div class="dropdown">
                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="accessibilityOptionsID" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                 Accessibility options
                 <span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="accessibilityOptionsID">
                 <li><a id="darkMode" href="#">Dim Mode</a></li>
                 <li><a id="lightMode" href="#">Light Mode</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
                 </div>
                
                 </div>
              
              <tr>
                   <form id="currentNoteEdit">
                   <!--Use <textarea> tag for multiline support-->
                   <td width="70%" id="noteContentRow"><p id="noteContentID" placeholder="" >'.$row["notes"].'</p><br></br></td>
                   </form>
              </tr>

        <td id="deleteAndEditContainerID">
        <button type="button" class="btn deleteButton '.$row["noteTitle"].'" id="" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSelectedNoteModal">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn editButton '.$row["noteTitle"].'" id="" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSelectedNoteModal">Edit</button>
        </td>

              ';  

              
    }  

    
    $output .= '</table>
    
    </div>

    <!--REMEMBER TO USE A JAVASCRIPT TEXT EDITOR FOR THESE LINES OF CODES BECAUSE IT IS DIFFICULT TO SPOT ERRORS WITHOUT PROPER SYNTAX CHECKING!!!!!-->
    <script>
    
    </script>

    
    </body>
    </html>';  
    echo $output;  
  }
  
  
?>
```

When user clicks .editButton, it will open another modal from another file, and that modal should be able to display the selected record so it can be edited in TiyMCE text editor, this is that modal:

```
<!--Start of modal for editing selected note-->
<div class="modal fade" id="editSelectedNoteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelTitle">
          <!--If we want to change the modal title dynamically, maybe we shall just initialize a hidden table where we can fetch the current id of the selected note-->
</h5>
        
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modalBodyOfEditingNote">
        Edit
        <textarea id="editNoteArea"> </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="cancelEditNote" class="btn btn-secondary pull-left">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="saveEditNote" class="btn btn-secondary pull-right">Save changes</button>
        <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End of modal for editing selected note-->
```

However, console.log(content); from my script only returns this:
[the file with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBRRn.png)

It doesn't really return the result of my sql query, rather it returns the whole string of var content, so nothing is displayed or returned in my TinyMCE text editor. I already tried changing it to single quotes but I get a syntax error.

Compared that from my template guide which returns the proper result:
[proper result returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qcem.png)

- Already tried changing double quotes to single quotes, single quotes to double quotes, single/double quotes to backtick character
- Already tried directly importing an external jquery directly to my javascript file
- Already tried some solutions from this SO link: [How do I embed PHP code in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-do-i-embed-php-code-in-javascript)

What am I expecting:

- return the specific record from mysql database to TinyMCE text area editor when user clicks 'Edit' button, this button shall allow user to edit their selected note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found a solution! I just basically erased all the $output variables which are meant to store the HTML elements in sort of like a 'string' way and implemented a more standard way of having PHP, JavaScript, and HTML languages in a file. Here is the full solution:

```html
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tnstudentregistrationdb");

if (isset($_POST["note_id"])) {
    $output = '';

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "tnstudentregistrationdb");  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM studentNotes WHERE noteid = '".$_POST["note_id"]."'";  
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
    

      //For NOTE EDITING!!!
       $querySpecific = "SELECT notes FROM studentNotes WHERE noteid = '".$_POST["note_id"]."'";
       $result2 = mysqli_query($connect, $querySpecific);
       $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);

       

       
?>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="selectNoteStyle.css"/>-->
    <!--There seems to be a problem with my external CSS, for now we will just use inline CSS-->

    <style>
    #deleteAndEditContainerID{
      text-align: left;
      
    }
  
  
  #noteTitleSelected {
      text-align: center;
      
  }
  
  #accessibilityOptionsID {
      float: right;
      
  }
  
  #noteContentID {
      width: 90%; 
      display: inline-block;
  }

  table, th, td, tr {
    /*We can also use ID and class to better specify which element to style, but since we only have one table
    in this component, we can also just call the entire table*/

    border: none;
  }
    </style>

    <script>
      
$(document).ready(
  function mode(){
  $("#darkMode").click(function(){
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.backgroundColor = "#ffcc66";
       document.getElementById("noteContentRow").style.backgroundColor = "#ffcc66";
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.color = "white";
      });
  
      $("#lightMode").click(function(){
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.backgroundColor = "white";
       document.getElementById("noteContentRow").style.backgroundColor = "white";
       document.getElementById("noteContentID").style.color = "black";
      });


      $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
       //Basically, .attr() gets the attribute value from $(this).attr("id"). so this could be $(".className").attr("id"), the id of the .className is selected.
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
       
       var title_note = $("#noteTitleSelected").text();
       var title_id_note = $("#noteIDSelected").text();

       $("#titleDeletingNoteID").text(title_note);
       $("#titleID").text(title_id_note);

       $("#myModal").modal("hide");
 
       
     }); //End of line for $(".deleteButton").click(function()){};

     
     $('.editButton').click(function(){
       //Basically, .attr() gets the attribute value from $(this).attr("id"). so this could be $(".className").attr("id"), the id of the .className is selected.
       event.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload
       
       $("#myModal").modal("hide");

       var content = '<?php echo $row1['notes']?>';
       //Try to use an external JavaScript file, using quotes in this js code is causing problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352576/how-do-i-embed-php-code-in-javascript
       console.log(content);
       
       tinymce.get("editNoteArea").setContent(content);
       
     }); //End of line for $(".editButton").click(function()){};
   
    
 });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>  
         <table >
          <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
    {  
      ?>
         
              
                 <h2 id="noteTitleSelected"><?php echo $row["noteTitle"] ?></h2>
                 <h4 id="noteIDSelected"><?php echo $row["noteid"] ?></h4> <!--Make Delete and Edit functional-->
                 <div id="menuAbove">
                 <label><i>Timestamp: <?php echo $row["note_timestamp"] ?></i></label>
                 
                 <div class="dropdown">
                 <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="accessibilityOptionsID" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                 Accessibility options
                 <span class="caret"></span>
               </button>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="accessibilityOptionsID">
                 <li><a id="darkMode" href="#">Dim Mode</a></li>
                 <li><a id="lightMode" href="#">Light Mode</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                 <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
               </ul>
                 </div>
                
                 </div>
              
              <tr>
                   <form id="currentNoteEdit">
                   <!--Use <textarea> tag for multiline support-->
                   <td width="70%" id="noteContentRow"><p id="noteContentID" placeholder="" ><?php echo $row["notes"] ?></p><br></br></td>
                   </form>
              </tr>

        <td id="deleteAndEditContainerID">
        <button type="button" class="btn deleteButton '.$row['noteTitle'].'" id="" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteSelectedNoteModal">Delete</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn editButton '.$row['noteTitle'].'" id="" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSelectedNoteModal">Edit</button>
        </td>

             <?php 
    }  
    ?>

    
    
    
    </div>

    <!--REMEMBER TO USE A JAVASCRIPT TEXT EDITOR FOR THESE LINES OF CODES BECAUSE IT IS DIFFICULT TO SPOT ERRORS WITHOUT PROPER SYNTAX CHECKING!!!!!-->
    <script>
    
    </script>

    
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
  }
  
  ?>
```